# Can't pass parameter to laravel excel constructor method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to pass variable to Laravel excel objects through constructor

```
public function exportSupplierStock()
{
    $supplier = \App\Models\Supplier::find(Session::get('materialPurchase-supplier'));
    $branch = \App\Models\Branch::where('supplier_id', $supplier->id)->first();

    return \Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::download(new \App\Exports\MaterialStockExport(
        $branch->id,
        false
    ), 'Material Stock ' . $supplier->name . '.xlsx');
}
```

Laravel excel constructor :

```
protected $branch;
protected $withMovement;

public function __construct($branch = null, $withMovement = true)
{
    $this->branch = $branch;
    $this->withMovement = $withMovement;
}
```

However when i'm trying to access those variables, it seems didn't passed

```
public function query()
{
    $query = MaterialStock::with(['material', 'branch']);

    $this->branch !== null ? $branch = $this->branch : $branch = Session::get('materialStock-branch');

    if (!in_array($branch, ['all', null])) $query->where('branch_id', $branch);

    return $query;
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: How do you access those variables? Can you provide more your code?

Comment: @KhangTran, i updated the access method in question, please check, briefly i've been trying to access them inside laravel excel's query method

Comment: query() is a method of MaterialStockExport class, right?

Comment: @KhangTran yes, correct

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @KhangTran no error, just null, because i set the default parameter inn the constructor, but the actual value i've passed seems unaccessible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253045/discussion-between-khang-tran-and-owf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the sheets method is called before query method

In sheets methods you create a new instance of MaterialStockExport: $sheets[] = new \App\Exports\MaterialStockExport;

You didn't pass values in that instance, so $branch and $withMovement of it will be null and true.

And they are the values you dump.

For multiple sheets, you should create a sheet class:

```
/**
 * MaterialStockExport just implements WithMultipleSheets
 * Move headings(),  query(), map() methods to sheet class
 */
class MaterialStockExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{ 
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];

        $currentPeriod = \App\Models\Period::where('status', 1)->first();
        $startDay = $currentPeriod->name;
        $endDay = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $startDay)->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');

        $this->branch !== null ? $branch = $this->branch : $branch = Session::get('materialStock-branch');

        if ($this->withMovement === true) {
            $sheets[] = new \App\Exports\MaterialMovementSheet(
                in_array($branch, ['all', null]) ? null : $branch,
                $startDay,
                $endDay
            );
        } else {
            $sheets[] = new \App\Exports\MaterialMovementSheet;
        }

        return $sheets;
    }
}

class MaterialMovementSheet implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, WithStrictNullComparison, WithMapping
{
    protected $branch;
    protected $startDay;
    protected $endDay;

    public function __construct($branch = null, $startDay = null, $endDay = null)
    {
        $this->branch = $branch;
        $this->startDay = $startDay;
        $this->endDay = $endDay;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return ['Cabang', 'Kategori', 'Kode Barang', 'Nama Barang', 'Stok Awal', 'Masuk', 'Keluar', 'Penyesuaian', 'Stok Akhir'];
    }

    /**
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function query()
    {
        $query = MaterialStock::with(['material', 'branch']);

        $this->branch !== null ? $branch = $this->branch : $branch = Session::get('materialStock-branch');

        if (!in_array($branch, ['all', null])) $query->where('branch_id', $branch);

        return $query;
    }

    public function map($stock): array
    {
        if (auth()->user()->role_id == 7) {
            $in = $stock->in + $stock->in_add;
            $out = $stock->out + $stock->out_add;
        }

        return [
            $stock->branch->name,
            $stock->material->group,
            $stock->material->item_code,
            $stock->material->name,
            $stock->begin_stock,
            $in ?? $stock->in,
            $out ?? $stock->out,
            $stock->adjustment,
            $stock->end_stock
        ];
    }
}
```